Why is hydrogen missing from mass spectrometry results?
I'm trying to get a better understanding of how mass spectrometry works, and how to read the results. I feel that I currently have a good grasp of how the process works, and now I'm looking at data collected from mass spectrometry (EI specifically) and trying to understand how to identify molecules from those results. What I noticed is that examples online tended to not display the amount of hydrogen hitting the detector. For an example in this case, I'm using results from the NIST data base for methane but I've had similar questions with other molecules. (https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74828&Mask=200)
Why are there no peaks shown for the hydrogen atoms being knocked free from the methane or other molecules that I've looked at? Is it just not displayed by the NIST graph? Do the hydrogen atoms that get knocked pick up an electron to become neutral, and hence fly right through? What's going on?
